# Delete channel commands erroring on run (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delete'))

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to add this joke command to my friend-community server which deletes a set of channels triggered by "execute order 66" it's erroring (error below and code). Help would be appreciated! :)

```
const fetchedChannel1 = client.guilds.cache.get('1004126581112975472');
const fetchedChannel2 = client.guilds.cache.get('1004126603963535570');
const fetchedChannel3 = client.guilds.cache.get('1004127515771666462');
const fetchedChannel4 = client.guilds.cache.get('1004127581836161186');
const fetchedChannel5 = client.guilds.cache.get('1004127590845534228');

client.on('message', async message => {
  if ((message.author.id) === bannedid) {
    if (message.content === 'execute order 66') {
      await message.react('');
    }

  } else if (message.content === 'execute order 66') {
    message.reply('yes my lord :innocent:'),
    fetchedChannel1.delete();
    fetchedChannel2.delete();
    fetchedChannel3.delete();
    fetchedChannel4.delete();
    fetchedChannel5.delete();
  }
  }
);
```

```
2022-08-02T20:55:49.118653+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delete')
2022-08-02T20:55:49.118673+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.<anonymous> (/app/bot.js:67:21)
2022-08-02T20:55:49.118673+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.emit (node:events:539:35)
2022-08-02T20:55:49.118694+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageCreateAction.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:34:18)
2022-08-02T20:55:49.118711+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE]
```

Comment: Have you tried putting those const inside the function and change `client` to `message` for the const

Comment: Can you please show an example?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "deletes a set of servers"? 
Are you trying to delete a server or a channel in a server?
or are you just trying to make it seem like you deleted a couple servers?

Comment: delete a set of channels not servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fetching each channel you can create an array of IDs , where each ID is the ID of the channel you want to delete. Then filter the guild's channels and delete the ones that match.

```
else if (message.content === 'execute order 66') {
  message.reply('yes my lord :innocent:');

  const channelsID = 
   [
     "1004126581112975472", "1004126603963535570", "1004127515771666462", 
     "1004127581836161186", "1004127590845534228"
   ]

  const guild = message.guild;
  // filter the channels that match the ID
  const filteredChannels = guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channelsID.includes(channel.id))

  // Delete each channel that has been filtered
  filteredChannels.forEach(channel => channel.delete());
```

}